# SQL count total number of days by customer

Tags: sql

I have a table `customer` which contains 2 columns, 1 is a `customer_id` column, and the other one is a date column named `order_date` that records what dates did the customers purchased a product. Now I want to count for how many days each customer went in and made a purchase. I tried to do the following but only got an error message saying `sum(date)` doesn't exist.

```
select customer_id, sum(order_date)
from customer;
```

How can I do this correctly?

---- Edit, adding the query to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
  "customer_id" VARCHAR(1),
  "order_date" DATE
);

INSERT INTO sales
  ("customer_id", "order_date")
VALUES
  ('A', '2021-01-01'),
  ('A', '2021-01-01'),
  ('A', '2021-01-07'),
  ('A', '2021-01-10'),
  ('A', '2021-01-11'),
  ('A', '2021-01-11'),
  ('B', '2021-01-01'),
  ('B', '2021-01-02'),
  ('B', '2021-01-04'),
  ('B', '2021-01-11'),
  ('B', '2021-01-16'),
  ('B', '2021-02-01'),
  ('C', '2021-01-01'),
  ('C', '2021-01-01'),
  ('C', '2021-01-07');
```

Comment: Why is `order_date` a `datetime` column if it only stores date information and not time?

Comment: `sum(date)` doesn't exist, but `sum(order_date)` does - please correct your post - and please post your full `CREATE TABLE customer` statement.

Comment: I added the query to create the table. And ```sum(date)``` is not an error, this is exactly the error message I got.

Comment: We still need you to post your `CREATE TABLE` statement - we really can't help you without it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I included it...

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: Why were you doing `SUM` in the first place? Adding dates together is an undefined operation (usually...), because it's nonsensical to ask "what's next tuesday plus today?")

Comment: I did a little research and found something saying "sum" or "avg" could do the work... which seems untrue... I was using MYSQL. what other ways can I take to get the total number of days a customer made a purchase?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want just this:

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    COUNT( DISTINCT "order_date" ) AS count_days_they_bought_something
FROM
    sales
GROUP BY
    customer_id
```

Comment: thank you... I started with Count(distinct order_date), and it didn't work, that's why I tried the sum() function... Now it is working...